# How do I increase the max open files in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, kernel, ulimit, launchctl, macos-bigsur

I have heard

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 64000 unlimited
```

And

```
conf=/etc/sysctl.conf
if sudo cat $conf | command rg kern.maxfiles ; then
  ecerr "kern.maxfiles is already set in $conf"
else
  sudo echo 'kern.maxfiles=40480
kern.maxfilesperproc=28000' >> "$conf"
fi
```

For previous versions of macOS, but none of these work in Big Sur.

Answer (score 11):

/etc/sysctl.conf is no longer supported with Big Sur. To make persistent changes systctl can be issued on boot time using a launch daemon in /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.startup.sysctl.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.startup.sysctl</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/sysctl</string>
        <string>kern.maxfiles=40480</string>
        <string>kern.maxfilesperproc=28000</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and install it with

```
chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.startup.sysctl.plist
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.startup.sysctl.plist
```

Comment: What security settings need to be flipped to allow writing into ` /Library/LaunchDaemons/` directory? It seems to be protected by Big Sur.

Comment: I was using a terminal session as root and a curses-based text editor

Answer (score 7):

I have used the following technique with success on Big Sur v11.6

So it seems that there are multiple settings at play here.

The numbers returned by `ulimit -Sn` and `ulimit -Hn` for soft and hard per process limits.

The the numbers returned by `launchctl limit maxfiles` the first of which is a soft per process limit and the second a hard per process limit.

Then the results of `sysctl -a | grep maxfiles` which shows `kern.maxfiles` and `kern.maxfilesperproc` where `kern.maxfiles` should be the hard limit for all processes and `kern.maxfilesperproc` should be the hard limit for a single process.

It seems I can permanently set all of these by adding a file at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`

with the following content, where 524288 corresponds to the soft limit and 16777216 to the hard limit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>launchctl</string>
      <string>limit</string>
      <string>maxfiles</string>
      <string>524288</string>
      <string>16777216</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

In order for the file to take effect you need to ensure that it's owned by root has group wheel.

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

You also need to load the daemon.

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

And finally to have this affect the output of `ulimit -Sn` and `ulimit -Hn` i needed to restart my machine.

Note: It seems like a mistake that setting a per process soft and hard limit via launchctl affects the kernel max per proc and max file limits, but that is what happens, so I've just chosen values large enough that I think its unlikely I will run into any trouble with them.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work anymore since macOS 13.4. launchctl is no longer allowed to run as admin, without disabling SIP.

Comment: Any updates for 13.4 or newer?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo sysctl kern.maxfiles=64000 kern.maxfilesperproc=28000
```

Unfortunately it will **not** persist over reboots.  Adding these to /etc/sysctl.conf does not appear to work in Big Sur.

To see your current settings use:

```
sysctl -a | grep maxfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this step works for me on Big Sur:

Enable server performance mode as describe below (don't forget to reboot)
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202528

Then this:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 9000000 9999999
```

And finally this (pay attention NOT to use sudo here):

```
ulimit -Sn 9000000
```

PS: Unfortunately the last two commands are not persist reboot, so they need to be done every time needed, or to include it on the script. Alternatively to add it at ~/.zshrc file on your Big Sur home directory.

Comment: (`ulimit` is a shell bultin, so using `sudo` with it is meaningless.)

Comment: You're right @HappyFace :)
Thank you for the correction... I've remove the sudo and in-fact it was not necessary and wrong in the first place.